GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS working in local but in production environment is not
I have a .NET 7.0 API that is using the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env to search Firebase. Using the same authentication JSON I can search Firebase by running the application locally. However, when publishing the application in a docker container and doing the same search I get an error "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project." I just need to know if the problem is in the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env in the docker image, or in the Google Cloud API and services settings.
I tried to create an Oauth 2.0 in my Cloud application as the website "https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project" teaches but without success. and also locally it works without problems
here is the dockerfile:
...
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/app/Credential-7291824fb310.json
ENV PROJECT_ID=XXXXXXXXX

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/dist/ /app
COPY ./Credential-7291824fb310.json .

EXPOSE 5002

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myAPP.API.dll"]

here is the stacktrace
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HN8NVLQG0G1Q", Request id "0HN8NVLQG0G1Q:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unauthenticated", Detail="Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.")
         at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.HttpContentClientStreamReader`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.AsyncResponseStream`1.MoveNextAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Query.StreamResponsesAsync(ByteString transactionId, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean allowLimitToLast)+MoveNext()
         at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Query.StreamResponsesAsync(ByteString transactionId, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean allowLimitToLast)+MoveNext()
         at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Query.StreamResponsesAsync(ByteString transactionId, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean allowLimitToLast)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
         at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<ForEachAsync>g__Core|99_0[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 action, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/ForEach.cs:line 41
         at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<ForEachAsync>g__Core|99_0[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 action, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/ForEach.cs:line 41
         at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Query.GetSnapshotAsync(ByteString transactionId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)


Please could you include the full stack trace, and check that the credential in Credential-7291824fb310.json is definitely a service account?

yes it is a gserviceaccount with a key just for editing firebase

Are you able to test simpler operations, e.g. FirestoreDb.ListRootCollectionsAsync? If you could post a [mcve] that would help too.

When saying "locally" you mean on your dev-machine without any docker involved? So I suspect the problem is with creating the image and/or running the container. Can you check if the running container indeed contains the correct .json file. Do you mount any volumes that might hide the /app directory in your container at runtim?

Your question isn't a minimal repro and you only include part of the Dockerfile so we can't answer definitively but evidently your dotnet runtime is not seeing the environment variable at runtime. It is bad practice (dangerous) to include secrets in Dockerfiles and you should avoid setting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in Dockerfiles too because Application Default Credentials (ADC) uses the Metadata service to acquire credentials when GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is unset (which it can't be in your configuration) when run on Google compute services.

Assuming you have good reason for using a secret key (!), you should mount the secret and then reference it at runtime: [docker|podman] run --interactive ---tty --rm --volume=/path/to/key.json:/secrets/key.json --env=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/secrets/key.json for local and, when you deploy to a compute service, you can omit both and let ADC acquire the credentials from the Metadata service.

Investigating further I realized that it was not being authenticated because the server time did not match the time of the service's JWT Token generation.
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) There was a problem refreshing auth tokens for account xxxxxxx: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.'})

I'm not sure why he only started complaining now, but I adjusted the server's time zone and it started working again.
